# I wanted to call parent page method from child dialog page in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am new to xamarin forms and trying to understand this for like three hours now.

I used the below code to open the dialog:
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("DialogPopupManualConfigPage");

In 'DialogPopupManualConfigPage' dialog box, I have a to buttons, 'Complete' and 'Cancel'. When 'Complete' is clicked, I want to call a function which is located in the parent page that calls the dialog.

```
public DialogPopupManualConfigPage(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        CurrentProgressPercent = string.Format("{0:F0}% complete", 0.00);

        ConfigureCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await ConfigureAsync());
        CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await CloseAsync());
    }

    private async Task ConfigureAsync()
    {
        //call a method from parent viewModel
    }


    private async Task CloseAsync()
    {
        await NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: there are many ways you could approach this 1) pass a reference to the parent page  2) use a custom event in the child  3) use MessagingCenter  4) pass a completion delegate

Comment: Thank you @Jason. I tried passing the reference of the parent to the child and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is pass a viewModel reference to child page:

**ChildPage**:

```
myViewModel parentViewModel;

public DialogPopupManualConfigPage(myViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    parentViewModel = vm;
}

private async Task ConfigureAsync()
{
    //call a method from parent viewModel

    parentViewModel.test();
}
```

**ParentPage**:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    myViewModel currentViewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new DialogPopupManualConfigPage(currentViewModel));
    }
}

public class myViewModel {
    public void test() {}
}
```

Examples of using a [messagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center):

**ChildPage**:

```
private async Task ConfigureAsync()
{
    //call a method from parent viewModel
    MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "Hi");
}
```

**ParentPage**:

```
myViewModel currentViewModel;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(new Object(), "Hi", (sender) =>
    {
        // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received

        currentViewModel.test();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like below and works for me at the time:

When calling the DialogPopup:
- create navParams and pass 'this' to represent the current PARENT caller page.

```
NavigationParameters navParams = new NavigationParameters
{
    { "parent", this },
};

await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("DialogPopupManualConfigPage", navParams);
```

---

When the DialogPopup page is Loading:
-- create the below global variable

```
<Caller_Parent_Page> _parent;

public DialogPopupManualConfigPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, <Caller_Parent_Page> parent) : base(navigationService)
{
    //accept the passed input and assign it to the global variabl
    _parent = parent;
}
```

---

Where I want to call the function:
- Simply check if global variable is not null

```
if(_parent != null)
{
    //call any public function from the Parent Page
    _parent.AreWeOnSameBranch()
}
```